# How to get notified as soon as a file is not open anymore?

Tags: c#, .net, file, filesystems

I need to listen on a directory and determine exactly (or within a few seconds) when a file is not open anymore.

How do I do this in C#?

Answer (score 2):

Windows doesn't support notifications for this.  Use a 'few second' timer to periodically retry.

Comment: thats not true http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.onchanged.aspx

Comment: @joe So, if somebody reads a file on a filesystem that doesn't update access times, how will that tell me that they closed the file handle?

Comment: AFAIK, "Last access time" updates are [disabled by default](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2006/11/07/disabling-last-access-time-in-windows-vista-to-improve-ntfs-performance.aspx) in Windows Vista and 7. Regardless, it'd only tell you when the file was last *accessed*, not when it was closed.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx), I think it would help you.

Good luck!

Comment: It doesn't appear that it would help; there's no applicable `NotifyFilter` for file closure.